# Android app becomes unresponsive when back button is pressed and crashes on android emulator

Tags: android, android-activity, intentservice

My app consists of two activities.In the first activity some input is taken from the user and passed to the second activity through intent. The second activity starts two `IntentServices` to perform some long-running background tasks. I have a **stop** button which stops the services. When I try to press the back button after stopping the services, the previous activity loads but the app becomes unresponsive and closes down. I tried to solve the problem by going through suggestions on this site but still the problem persists.

**code for starting 2nd activity from 1st**

```
Intent intent = new Intent(ConnectActivity.this, MessageActivity.class);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY);
intent.putExtra("ip", ip);
intent.putExtra("port", port);
intent.putExtra("tcpport", tcpport);
intent.putExtra("tcpip", tcpip);
intent.putExtra("packetType", PT);
startActivity(intent);
```

**code for `backButtonPressed()` from 2nd activity**

```
public void onBackPressed() {
    if(UdpSendService.send)
    while(!endTransmission());
    //Intent intent = new Intent(this, ConnectActivity.class);
    //intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY);
    //startActivity(intent);
    finish();
    //super.onBackPressed();
}
```

**the `endTransmission()` method**

```
boolean endTransmission() {
    UdpSendService.send=false;
    if(receiver1!=null && receiver2!=null){
        unregisterReceiver(receiver1);
        unregisterReceiver(receiver2);
        receiver1=null;
        receiver2=null;
    }
    while(stopService(udpReceiveIntent)!=true);
    System.out.println("\nreceive service stopped");
    while(stopService(udpServiceIntent)!=true);
    System.out.println("\nsend service stopped");
    return true;
}
```

**logcat:**

```
01-22 15:18:39.893: E/ActivityManager(162): ANR in com.example.udpmessageclient (com.example.udpmessageclient/.ConnectActivity)
01-22 15:18:39.893: E/ActivityManager(162): Reason: keyDispatchingTimedOut
01-22 15:18:39.893: E/ActivityManager(162): Load: 1.39 / 1.05 / 0.66
01-22 15:18:39.893: E/ActivityManager(162): CPU usage from 12723ms to 0ms ago:
01-22 15:18:39.893: E/ActivityManager(162):   63% 162/system_server: 53% user + 9.6% kernel / faults: 593 minor
01-22 15:18:39.893: E/ActivityManager(162):   35% 1467/com.example.udpmessageclient: 27% user + 7.9% kernel / faults: 44 minor
01-22 15:18:39.893: E/ActivityManager(162):   0.1% 293/com.android.phone: 0.1% user + 0% kernel / faults: 4 minor
01-22 15:18:39.893: E/ActivityManager(162): 99% TOTAL: 82% user + 17% kernel
01-22 15:18:39.893: E/ActivityManager(162): CPU usage from 3151ms to 3707ms later:
01-22 15:18:39.893: E/ActivityManager(162):   58% 162/system_server: 47% user + 10% kernel
01-22 15:18:39.893: E/ActivityManager(162):     9% 334/Binder_3: 9% user + 0% kernel
01-22 15:18:39.893: E/ActivityManager(162):     7.2% 173/Binder_1: 5.4% user + 1.8% kernel
01-22 15:18:39.893: E/ActivityManager(162):     7.2% 174/Binder_2: 7.2% user + 0% kernel
01-22 15:18:39.893: E/ActivityManager(162):     5.4% 162/system_server: 3.6% user + 1.8% kernel
01-22 15:18:39.893: E/ActivityManager(162):     5.4% 195/InputDispatcher: 1.8% user + 3.6% kernel
01-22 15:18:39.893: E/ActivityManager(162):     5.4% 336/Binder_4: 3.6% user + 1.8% kernel
01-22 15:18:39.893: E/ActivityManager(162):     5.4% 367/Binder_5: 5.4% user + 0% kernel
01-22 15:18:39.893: E/ActivityManager(162):     5.4% 374/Binder_6: 5.4% user + 0% kernel
01-22 15:18:39.893: E/ActivityManager(162):     5.4% 380/Binder_7: 3.6% user + 1.8% kernel
01-22 15:18:39.893: E/ActivityManager(162):     5.4% 383/Binder_8: 3.6% user + 1.8% kernel
01-22 15:18:39.893: E/ActivityManager(162):   39% 1467/com.example.udpmessageclient: 28% user + 10% kernel / faults: 2 minor
01-22 15:18:39.893: E/ActivityManager(162):     35% 1467/dpmessageclient: 25% user + 10% kernel
01-22 15:18:39.893: E/ActivityManager(162): 100% TOTAL: 78% user + 21% kernel
01-22 15:18:43.783: E/InputDispatcher(162): channel '4119ec38 com.example.udpmessageclient/com.example.udpmessageclient.ConnectActivity (server)' ~ Channel is unrecoverably broken and will be disposed!
01-22 15:18:43.853: E/InputDispatcher(162): Received spurious receive callback for unknown input channel.  fd=187, events=0x9
01-22 15:21:45.544: E/Trace(1523): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
01-22 15:21:46.265: E/ActivityThread(278): Failed to find provider info for com.android.inputmethod.latin.dictionarypack
01-22 15:21:46.265: E/BinaryDictionaryGetter(278): Could not find a dictionary pack
01-22 15:21:46.355: E/ActivityThread(278): Failed to find provider info for com.android.inputmethod.latin.dictionarypack
01-22 15:21:46.355: E/BinaryDictionaryGetter(278): Could not find a dictionary pack
```

Comment: post the logcat error report..

Comment: `while(!endTransmission());` locks the ui thread. don't do that. just call the stopService once for each service and let them finish themselves.

Comment: The solution is very much what njzk2 suggested. The problem is with your while loop as I suggested. You need to stop service and then don't care, let them finish.

Comment: @njzk2 @VendettaDroid : I agree with what you both suggested and changed my code to :

`public void onBackPressed() {
  if(UdpSendService.send)
  endTransmission();
  finish();
  
 }`
still the same thing occurs. Maybe the problem lies elsewhere, could be the IntentServices.

Comment: In my program the `endTransmission()` method is called when the **stop** button is pressed. while testing I press the stop button first and then the back button. Hence the `UdpSendService.send` variable is already set to `false`, and therefore `endTransmission()` does not execute when back button is pressed. So I guess the problem is not caused by `endTransmission()`

Comment: the loop is in endTransmission ... doesn't matter if you call it in onBackPressed or when you press a stop button.

Comment: @njzk2 yeah you were right, I removed the loop within `endTransmission()` and now its working :) Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be your problem is in this part of code:

```
public void onBackPressed() {
    if(UdpSendService.send)
    while(!endTransmission());
    //Intent intent = new Intent(this, ConnectActivity.class);
    //intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY);
    //startActivity(intent);
    finish();
    //super.onBackPressed();
}
```

You are spending enough(little too much) time in your while loop as it blocks UI thread to get unresponsiveness in your app.

Answer (score 1):

while(!endTransmission());

is looking more dangerous, coz this loop locks ui thread. 
Your activity took too long to say to the Android OS 'hey i'm still alive'! (This is what the UI thread does).

[Application Responsiveness time](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/design/responsiveness.html)

Answer (score 0):

delay the process for 1 sec rather than using while.
use handler postdelay method.

Answer (score 0):

Application should not block main thread more than 5 seconds. Make your app more responsive using thread and handler.
http://developer.android.com/training/articles/perf-anr.html